# Query time increases dramatically due to poor execution plan

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have a *relatively* complex query like the one that follows

```sql
select * from (
  select
      distinct on("car")
      entity.id as "car",
      metric as "last_visit"
  from now() ref_date
  cross join (values (142), (432), (583), (448), (381)) entity(id)
  left join (
    select
        gv.car_id as _entity_id,
        gv.start as _tc_past,
        gv.start as _keep_max_of,
        g.name as metric
    from garage_visits gv
    left join garage_tree_flat gtf on gtf.descendant_id = gv.garage_id
    left join garage g on g.id = gtf.parent_id
    where true
    and price != 0
    and  g.type = 2
  ) x
  on x._entity_id = entity.id
    and _tc_past < ref_date
    and _tc_past >= ref_date - interval '12 weeks'
    order by "car", _keep_max_of desc
) t
where t."last_visit" is not null;
```

My problem is that the query running time will vary tremendously based on the number of elements that are present in `cross join (values (...))`.

Namely, I have the following average running times depending on how many `values` there are:

| values | avg running time |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 25ms |
| 2 | 30ms |
| 3 | 35ms |
| 4 | 40ms |
| 5 | 4900ms |
| 6 | 4900ms |
| 7 | 4900ms |

Checking the execution plan for both versions (up to 3 values or more than 3 values) shows that the culprit is the index scan on `garage_visits gv`. This table contains several million rows.

In the case of up to 3 `car_ids`, the index condition on `garage_visits` is as follows:

```sql
Node Type: Index Scan
Index Name: ix_gv_car_id
Index Cond: (gv.car_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
Actual Duration: 0.687ms
```

In the case of more than 3 `car_ids`, the index condition on `garage_visits` is as follows:

```sql
Node Type: Index Scan
Index Name: ix_gv_garage_id
Index Cond: (gv.garage_id = gtf.descendant_id)
Actual Duration: 3386.068ms
```

As we can observe, with up to three values, the query planner decides to filter `garage_visits` by `car_id`, and outputs only these rows, which is extremely fast. But with more than three car_id values, the planner decides against using this information and instead filters `garage_visits` by `gtf.descendant_id` instead, which dramatically changes the execution time because there are many more `gtf.descendant_id` values than there are `car_ids` values.

Is there a way to keep using the "up to 3 values" way but with more than 3 values? It looks like it's simply a wrong estimation here from the query planner and it's frustrating to see that this query could run really fast (even for 30 or 50 values) but instead spends a lot of wasted time.

Comment: note: unless some useful answers/comments are posted here, I'm going to delete this question soon from StackOverflow and post it on dba.stackexchange instead

Comment: Not sure why you are using a CROSS JOIN instead of `IN (142,432,583,448,381)` someplace. A cross join returns a ton of rows - every row with every other row on both sides of the join. It should be avoided unless really required.